# How to add Buttons dynamically one after another

Tags: java, android, button, dynamic, timedelay

I want to add a specific number of Buttons on random positions to my Relativ Layout with the method  createButton.
But the Buttons should appear one after another and not all at the same time and I have no idea how to achieve this.

Thanks all.

```
public void createButton(int amountOfButtons) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int i1 = r.nextInt(300);
    int i2 = r.nextInt(300);

    Button myButton = new Button(this);
    myButton.setText("Push Me");

    RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rela);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
    lp.setMargins(i1,i2,0,0);
    myButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
    ll.addView(myButton); 

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (amountOfButtons > 1) {
        createButton(amountOfButtons-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your UI thread to remain active, you need to put this in a separate thread with something like an AsyncTask so that your sleep doesn't freeze your UI. Something like

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer param, Void, Void>{
    private int time = 0;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer...time){
        this.time = time[0];

        try {
           Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        createButton(time-1);
    }
}
```

Then do something like this in your activity

```
private MyAsyncTask task;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    int time;
    // Some methodology to get the desired time
    createButton(time);
    new MyAsyncTask().execute(time -1);
}
```

With your method changed to

```
public void createButton(int time) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int i1 = r.nextInt(300);
    int i2 = r.nextInt(300);

    Button myButton = new Button(this);
    myButton.setText("Push Me");

    RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rela);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
    lp.setMargins(i1,i2,0,0);
    myButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
    ll.addView(myButton); 

    if(time == 0) 
        return;
    else 
        new MyAsynCTask().execute(time);
}
```

Comment: I have tried a lot with this AsyncTask, but it doesn't work properly...
My main problem right now is, that the AsyncTask can be executed only once(so I can't use a loop like you suggested). And if I generate a new Instance of the AsyncTask I don't get the buttons one by one, but all together again ...

Comment: Sorry I can't follow your ideas...
in the onCreate method you declare the variable time, but you don't initialise it, then you want to call the createButton method with time?! Furthermore needs the doInBackground method an integer-Array not a simple integer. And if I change all the errors the app doesn't even start, I think the timer doesn't change much, but thanks for your help nontheless ;)

Comment: @user3537599 Read the comment under int time; It states that that is where you will do whatever it is to get the desired time. If the time is arbitrary, just change it to something like int time = 5; And why do you need to pass an array? If you do just change it to an array that you pass

Comment: Okay I understand the first problem. 
to the second problem : I don't need to pass an array, but the method doInBackground(Integer...time) produces an array named time. And your code "this.time = time;" wants to add the type int[] to int ;)
And the new Code still executes the AsyncTask multiple times :/
"The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)" - from the Android Api.

Comment: @user3537599 Look at my edit, made a few more mistakes that I fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  you just want to use simple for loop ?

Comment: The for loop won't keep his UI active though. He can add buttons, but wouldn't be able to click them until they were all added